# How to change button appearance of custom registered block style?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I registered a style of WordPress core gallery block with this code:

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/gallery', {
    name: 'hot-carousel',
    label: 'Hot Carousel'
} );
```

Is it possible to change the appearance of the button?

[image: button appearance]

Comment: Which button are you actually talking about?

Comment: See my screenshot. How do I change the image above the Hot Carousel text?

Comment: What kind of appearance you need? If there are no markup changes then that can be done by simple css.